# Android USB communication with Infineon XMC4500 Relax Kit

Tags: java, android, eclipse, usb

I am very beginner in stuff which I am doing.
My problem is that: I am programming an Android application in order to be able to send data and receive data from Infineon XMC4500 processor, I am working with my evaluation board Infineon XMC4500 Relax kit.

Could you please tell me, what actually do I do wrong in order to send data.

I would like to to add, that in Infineon DAVE IDE (IDE based on eclipse), I use DAVE app (software component) USBVC001 (USB_VirtualCOMDevice_USBVC001 is App for Communications Device Class demonstration application.)

Every suggestion is highly appreciated!

```
com.example.mateusz.buttonexample;

android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    final int RQSID_SET_LINE_CODING = 0x20;
    final int RQSID_SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE = 0x22;

    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.example.USB_PERMISSION";
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    private final int vendorID = 1419;
    private final int productID = 88;
    PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;

    private UsbDevice device;
    private UsbManager connectedDevices;

    UsbEndpoint in = null;
    UsbEndpoint out = null;
    UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection = null;
    UsbInterface interfaceUSB = null;

    private Button checkButton;

    private TextView infoDevice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UsbDevice device1 = null;
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);
        mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

        registerReceiver(mUsbDeviceReceiver, new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED));
        registerReceiver(mUsbDeviceReceiver, new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED));

        //UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
            device1 = deviceIterator.next();
            //your code
        }



        device = device1;
        manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);

        infoDevice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoDevice);
        checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkButton);


        checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showInformationAboutConnectedDevices();
            }
        });

        //setUpCommunication();
    }

    private  void releaseUsb()
    {
        if(usbDeviceConnection != null)
        {
            if(interfaceUSB != null)
            {
                usbDeviceConnection.releaseInterface(interfaceUSB);
                interfaceUSB = null;
            }
            usbDeviceConnection.close();
            usbDeviceConnection = null;
        }
        in = null;
        out = null;
        usbDeviceConnection = null;
        device = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        releaseUsb();
        unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(mUsbDeviceReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void setUpCommunication()
    {
        UsbDevice usbDevice = null;
        UsbDevice usbDeviceFound = null;

        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();



        while(deviceIterator.hasNext())
        {
            usbDevice = deviceIterator.next();

            //do sprawdzenia
            if((usbDevice.getVendorId() == vendorID) && (usbDevice.getProductId() == productID))
            {
                device = usbDevice;
                TextView check = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkText1);
                check.setText("Sprawdzony vendorID i productID");
            }

            if(device != null)
            {
                //TextView check = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkText1);
                //check.setText("Device != null");
                //wait(2000);

                //for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){ ; }
                for(int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++)
                {
                    UsbInterface usbInter = device.getInterface(i);

                    if(usbInter.getEndpointCount() >= 2){
                        for(int j = 0; j < usbInter.getEndpointCount(); j++)
                        {
                            if(usbInter.getEndpoint(j).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK)
                            {
                                if (usbInter.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN)
                                {
                                    in = usbInter.getEndpoint(j);
                                }

                                if(usbInter.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT)
                                {
                                    //check.setText("USB_DIR_OUT");
                                    //wait(2000);
                                    interfaceUSB = usbInter;
                                    out = usbInter.getEndpoint(j);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        TextView check = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkText1);
        TextView pozwolenie = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pozwolenie);

        if(manager.hasPermission(device)){ pozwolenie.setText("Wszedlem w pozwolenie"); }
        byte[] myBuffer = new byte[] {(byte)'A'};
        //Ustanowienie komunikacji
        UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(device);
        connection.claimInterface(interfaceUSB, true);

                int length = connection.bulkTransfer(out,myBuffer, myBuffer.length,100);

        if(length >= 0)
        {
            check.setText("Udalo sie " + Integer.toString(length));
        }

        byte[] tablica = new byte[1];
        tablica[0] = (byte)'B';
        int d = tablica[0];
        connection.bulkTransfer(in, tablica, 1, 100);
        int z = tablica[0];
        check.setText("B code" + Integer.toString(d) + "bulkTransfer" + Integer.toString(z));
        usbDeviceConnection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showInformationAboutConnectedDevices()
    {
        connectedDevices = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = connectedDevices.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceListIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

        String informationAboutDevice = "";
        while (deviceListIterator.hasNext())
        {
            UsbDevice connectedDeviceTemporary = deviceListIterator.next();

            String tempString;
            tempString = "\n";
            tempString = "Device id: " + connectedDeviceTemporary.getDeviceId() + "\n"
                    + "Device name:" + connectedDeviceTemporary.getDeviceName() + "\n" + "dupa";
            informationAboutDevice += tempString;
        }
        infoDevice.setText(informationAboutDevice);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            TextView permissionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPermission);

            if(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action))
            {
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    UsbDevice connectedDeviceTemporary = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                   // device = connectedDeviceTemporary;
                    if(intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false))
                    {
                        if(connectedDeviceTemporary != null)
                        {
                            permissionText.setText("Wszedlem w mUsbReceiver");
                            setUpCommunication();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbDeviceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action))
            {
                //UsbDevice device1 = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkingText);
                text.setText("Wszedlem mUsbDeviceReceiver ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED");
                if(usbDeviceConnection != null)
                {
                    if(interfaceUSB != null)
                    {
                        usbDeviceConnection.releaseInterface(interfaceUSB);
                        interfaceUSB = null;
                    }
                    usbDeviceConnection.close();
                    usbDeviceConnection = null;
                }
                in = null;
                out = null;
                usbDeviceConnection = null;
                device = null;

            }
            else if(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action))
            {
                device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkingText);
                text.setText("Wszedlem mUsbDeviceReceiver ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED");
                setUpCommunication();
            }
        }
    };
}
```